# Volume changes not being detected by docker programs

Tags: reactjs, docker, reload, alpine-linux, nodemon

I have mapped my directory (on host OS) to a directory in `docker`. When i make changes in host directory, they are refelcted in `Docker` directory but apps like `nodemon` or `react-hot-reloader` do not detect them and hence do not restart. However, hot reloading works fine when i make changes directly within docker. I am running an `express app`. I have tried two OSs (`node:alpine3.13` & `node:stretch-slim`)for Docker but hot reloading works on neither. I also tried installing `inotify-tools` on `alpine` but to no avail

Comment: Did you try using `-L` or `--legacy-watch` flag with nodemon? You can read more about it here: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting

Comment: @MayankPathela Thanks, this solves the issue with nodemon but it probably won't for other programs like react. Is there a general solution?

Comment: If I need a hot reloader, I generally use Node, not Docker.  Docker has some key design goals (immutable images, isolated from the host system) that don't match what you want for live reloading.  You can use Node for developing a component of the application even if its dependencies (databases, backend systems, other microservices) are in containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks, doesn't sound bad